# Creating an IWebBrowser2 control

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw

I just want to successfully add it to my window, and it has been surprisingly difficult.

I've tried

```
#include "windef.h"
#include "winbase.h"
#include "initguid.h"
#include "ole2.h"
#include "olectl.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"
#include "exdispid.h"
#include <objidl.h>
#include "OleIdl.h"
#include "Objbase.h" 

#include <exdisp.h>
#include <exdispid.h>

...

IWebBrowser2* pBrowser2;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&pBrowser2);
```

Getting

```
error: 'CLSID_InternetExplorer' undeclared (first use in this function)
     HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer,
```

I've also tried

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WebBrowser, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
                   IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&pBrowser2);
```

This one at least compiles, but nothing is added to the window:

```
    hr = OleCreate(&CLSID_WebBrowser, &IID_IOleObject, 1/*OLERENDER_DRAW*/, 0,
                            &ClientSite, &Storage, (void**)&mpWebObject);
```

I tried all headers and libraries I could find on the net (as you can see).

Here are the libraries I link:

```
gcc -lmingw32 -mwindows  -luser32 -lgdiplus -lole32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loleaut32 -lshdocvw -lmf -lmfuuid
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you use *c* - you need include `Uuid.Lib` to linker input - here defined `CLSID_InternetExplorer` and `IID_IWebBrowser2`. also you need use `CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL, &IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&pBrowser2);`

Comment: however you include `-luuid` - are in your version exist `CLSID_InternetExplorer` and `IID_IWebBrowser2` ? this is from ms sdk ?

Comment: @RbMm  I suspect MinGW doesn't have  these consts. If you have Visual Studio, maybe you could std::cout them ?

Comment: simply look in `uuid.lib` - are `CLSID_InternetExplorer` and `IID_IWebBrowser2` exist. in ms sdk - it exist.

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using

Comment: No GUI. gcc.exe.

Comment: So I found this `class DECLSPEC_UUID("0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
InternetExplorer;`

Comment: I tried to get the CLSID via `LPCLSID guid;
CLSIDFromString("{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", guid); `, but it crashes...

Comment: Passing uninitialized pointers to functions is a sure recipe for disaster. You need to pass a pointer to an actual GUID instance.

Comment: Of course. Fixed that, but now I get `'IWebBrowser2 {aka struct IW
ebBrowser2}' has no member named 'Navigate'
  NavigateResult = browser->Navigate(URL, &empty, &empt
y, &empty, &empty);
`

Comment: @Alex [yes, it most certainly does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa752133).

Comment: Of course it does :) It's defined in "ExDisp.h". And yet I get this error.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have a normal WinAPI window. @M.M

Comment: Looks like it's simply not possible with MinGW. I hope I can link a VS library with my MinGW build.

Comment: Yep, just installed Visual Studio, and it works there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: consider using mingw-w64 which is much more up to date with Windows API than mingw

Comment: @M.M mingw-w64 is amazing! It has a full version of ExDisp.h, and it works! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

This is a fork of MinGW which , in addition to supporting both 32-bit and 64-bit builds, is under much more active development. In particular, having improved Windows API headers.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently MinGW doesn't support IWebBrowser2. The code worked fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: @selbie the Windows SDK relies on non-standard MSVC compiler extensions  ; the bulk of the work for projects like mingw involves creating headers that will work with g++

Answer (score 0):

Start by including these header files first:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <ExDisp.h>
#include <ExDispid.h>
```

Then this:

```
IWebBrowser2* pBrowser2 = nullptr;
HRESULT hr;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(WebBrowser), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, __uuidof(IWebBrowser2), (void**)pBrowser2);
```

The use of __uuidof macro takes resolves the linkage issues to externally defined guids.

Comment: `__uuidof` is a Microsoft specific extension, only available in C++. The OP is using GCC and C.